# Spark View Engine "An assembly with the same simple name" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I am trying out the Spark view engine with ASP MVC but get the error below when displaying a view. The view references model objects that are in a different assembly to the main web application (MyApp.Model.dll). I am stuck on the cause or resolution to this.

Dynamic view compilation failed. 
0,0): error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name 
'MyApp.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the 
references or sign them to enable side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're referencing the same assembly multiple times in your view. Instead of using the `<use assembly="">` element you might want to use the `<use namesace="">` element

Comment: Thanks. I am also a bit confused about the _global.spark file and how it relates to this and spark engine setup in the global.aspx. Is there any good reference on this?

Comment: I had a look at this but am not using <use assembly=""> anywhere and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Craig I got the same problem, if I modify some class in assembly X and do a build, I got this error at runtime for the assembly X.

But after a "rebuild" (not "build") it's working.

For me it has been in the middle of a project. It comes maybe from an update ?

Matthieu